# Modelling fiber optic network using free solution in GIS?

Tags: software-recommendations, modelling, utility-network, telecom

I am a beginner to GIS software and currently I have been given a task to model a telecom network. Most of the solutions that I came across are proprietary.

I want to know which open source software can I use to show the connectivity between multiple fibers (FTTX network)?

I do not need a software to plan and design a network, I just have to make a replica of the network that I already have in KMLs.

Comment: pease elaborate a little more on that problem you encountered. also, what types of geometry do you have (polylines and/or points?), and what's your plans with them (e.g. how does your desired outcome look like?). recommendations on this would already be broad by nature, try clear things up a little more. in general, a common open source GIS stack uses QGIS to visualize and model by sight, often combined with a powerful PostgreSQL/PostGIS backend to store and efficiently spatially analyze your data...depending on your needs.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Often I have to point out the [Tour] admonition to ask "only one" question, but you haven't asked an actual question. Please [Edit] the question to contain your question, keeping in mind that soliciting a list of opinion-based suggestions or general discussion of best practices is forbidden here.

Comment: You can do a lot of vector network analysis with GRASS GIS, see https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/vectorintro.html#vector-network-analysis